# netkit: Connecting 3 routers and trying to ping router 3 to router 1

Tags: networking, virtual-machines

hey guys, I am using Netkit to simulate a network, I am using the static routing lab provided by Netkit and I am trying to set up 3 routers. I have 3 routers each with a pc connected.

pc1 on r1 can ping pc2 on r2 and vice versa.

pc3 on r3 can pnig pc2 on r2 and vice versa.

but pc1 cant ping pc3 on r3.

This is my problem I can't seem to get a connection between pc1 on router 1 to connect to pc3 on router 3.

Below is how I have configured the network:

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As UniSoft mentioned, please try drawing a diagram next time (even something crappy in paint), as they are much, much easier to follow than describing the network in prose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When PC3 makes a request for 195.11.0.0, then router3 does not know what to do with it.

Same with PC1 for 195.20.0.0 and router1.

Please make a diagram next time :-)

The configuration you made will keep router1 and router3 computers isolated/protected from each other, but they can both access servers on router2

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. Yes Ill make sure for next time.